# openssl x509 & rsa in perl - Net::SSLeay?

Tags: perl, encryption, openssl, rsa, x509certificate

I am trying to use the right library to make the following two calls in perl:

`openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.crt | openssl md5`

`openssl rsa  -noout -modulus -in server.key | openssl md5`

Are these the best options: 
CPAN_Crypt_OpenSSL_X509
CPAN_Crypt_OpenSSL_RSA

or can it be done in: Net::SSLeay ?

A pointer to an example will surely help.

Comment: These commands do not make much sense for me. What you are trying to get with these commands?

Comment: https://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4064

Comment: If your objective is to check if the private key matches the public key in the certificate you can simply use them together to built a test server. Apart from that Crypt::OpenSSL::X509 has a modules function and Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA a get_key_parameters which might help you.

Comment: without actually bringing up a server I wanted to validate these and thats the reason I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could just compare the hex strings of the moduli to achieve the same result, without doing a digest. `Crypt::OpenSSL::X509` and `Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA` have the necessary methods to do this:

```
my $x509_cert = Crypt::OpenSSL::X509->new_from_string('...');
my $pkey = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key('...');

my ($key_modulus) = $pkey->get_key_parameters;
if ($x509_cert->modulus eq $key_modulus->to_hex) {
  # same modulus
}
else {
  # different
}
```